# Nsstring objects changing its data type

Tags: iphone, crash, nsstring

I have a certain nsstring property declared in a variable, it is used to do store a text string when i am performing a parsing operation. As this parsing operation happens mulitple times, the Nsstring property changes bizzardly to any random data type and crashing my application. This happens when i try to compare the property with other  local variable which is also string. But by the time i compare, the appdelegate variable has already changed its data type, and hence crashes my app.

Any one ever come across such issue? If so, please guide me.

Comment: Please add the console output in order we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a sign that your NSString object has been deallocated so you send a message to a deallocated object. That crashes your application. The datatype changes because after an object is deallocated the memory it was placed in is not correct anymore and may contain a trash. You should use Run with Performance tool -> Leaks tool. It helps a lot in such cases. Please keep in mind that you should enable zombie object detection in settings.
[image]

Comment: I think KOS might be right. Though not using zombies, but after i changed my code, to explicitly release and create the variable every single time, the problem seems to have disappear. Thanks for the insight.. :)